# Calling function at regular intervals in node.js

Tags: node.js, memory

I have the below code in node.js . Its a long running background service which

1. scans a messages table for status = 0
2. reads date  from it
3. Sends email using Amazon SES
4. Updates the status to 1 in the messages table

If i run this on the my mac the memory usage is fairly constant below 30M.But when I run this on our CENTOS server the memory consumtion keeps increasing .I am fairly new to node.js .
Can some one guide me ?  Is this because of recursion ?

```
   var nodemailer = require('../lib/nodemailer'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    pathlib = require("path");
    var mysql = require("mysql");

    // Create an Amazon SES transport object
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SES", {
        AWSAccessKeyID: "xxxxxxx",
        AWSSecretKey: "yyyyyyyyy",
        ServiceUrl: "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" // optional
    });

    console.log('SES Configured');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        user: "user",
        password: "xxxxxx",
        database: "db_content"
    }); 

    // Message object

    function loop(){
        console.log("Reading from DB");
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM mm_messages where status = 0 limit 1;', function (error, rows, fields) {

            if( rows.length == 1 ) {        
                var message = {
                    from: 'abc <abc@xxxxx.com>',
                    to: rows[0]["to"],
                    subject: rows[0]["subject"] + rows[0]["id"], //
                    text: 'Hello to myself!',
                    html:'<p><b>Hello</b> to myself <img src="cid:note@node"/></p>'
                };

                console.log('Sending Mail');

                transport.sendMail(message, function(error){
                    if(error){
                        console.log('Error occured');
                        console.log(error.message);
                    //return;
                    }

                    console.log('Message sent successfully!');


                    connection.query('update mm_messages set status = 1 where id='+rows[0]["id"] + ';', function (errorq, rowsq, fieldsq) {
                        message = null;
                        error = null;
                        errorq = null;
                        rowsq = null;
                        rows = null;
                        fieldsq = null;
                        fields = null;
                        setTimeout(loop, 2000);     
                    });

                });
            } else {
                message = null;         
                rows = null;
                fields =null;
                error= null;
                setTimeout(loop, 2000);
            }

        });


    }

    loop();
```

Comment: There is no recursion. setTimeout resets the stack so you're fine from that perspective. Are you sure this isn't just normal "garbage collector hasn't run yet" behavior?

Comment: ok . But the Garbage collection is done automatically right ? We just need to make the unused references as null . Please advise .

Comment: You don't need to do anything, nor can you do anything. Marking as null is almost never actually useful. Just don't leak variables and don't hold references longer than necessary and let v8 do the rest. Keep in mind using up a lot of RAM is a good thing, at least initially. That's what RAM is there for. I wouldn't draw any conclusions without some decent code reviews and some more research and testing more extensively.

Comment: Can you look at the code ? I have done some testing . The memory usage keeps increasing . It increased from 21m to 60m  when it processed about 500 emails  in a span of 2 hrs .

Comment: The code itself looks ok. I mean there is no reason to get memory leak. You should search the reason in the dependencies. Replace the mysql queries with a simple callback and see if the memory still increases. Do the same with the mail sending.

Comment: I'd check if the node.js version and all the npm module versions match.

Comment: If I may ask : do you know how long does your CENTOS server approximately take to execute the two queries and to send the mail ?
It could be that the queue grows larger since the mysql driver might be too slow to answer queries

Comment: I also found that my above code works perfectly in node 0.8.16 ( in my Mac ) and the memory keeps inrceasing in CENTOS server which has 0.10.18 . I read some where that new V8 doesn't often call GC. Can anyone confirm this ?

Answer (score 0):

That still all looks pretty benign to me. Here's some things you could change and then re-measure.

- convert the inline anonymous callback function into a top-level named function.

  - `connection.query('SELECT * FROM mm_messages where status = 0 limit 1;', function (error, rows, fields) {`
  - `connection.query('SELECT * FROM mm_messages where status = 0 limit 1;', messageCallback`
- Use parameterized SQL instead of string concatenation to build your SQL update statement
- remove all those `foo = null;` statements. They are unnecessary. They are unidiomatic. They make your code longer than it needs to be. They are driven by FUD as opposed to having an actual purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply will try that . I also found that  my above code works perfectly in node 0.8.16 ( in my Mac ) and the memory keeps inrceasing in CENTOS server which has 0.10.18 . I read some where that new V8 doesn't often call GC. Can anyone confirm this ?